# SQL statement to find whole words

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a varchar(max) field, and I need to perform text searches on it. Specifically, I need to find whole words. I have tried

```
Select * From MyTable 
Where Col = @SearchTxt
Or    Col Like @SearchTxt + ' %'
Or    Col Like '% ' + @SearchTxt + ' %'
Or    Col Like '% ' + @SearchTxt
```

This works to a certain extent, but it does not give me the instances where the SearchTxt is before or after punctuations (like SearchTxt! or SearchTxt,)

Is there a reasonably easy way to get what I'm looking for, without having a whole bunch of where clauses? Also, the column is not indexed, and although speed is not the primary concern, I want the query to run reasonably fast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT <ColumnsList>
FROM MyTable
WHERE Col = @SearchText
OR Col LIKE @SearchTxt + '[^A-Za-z]%'
OR Col LIKE '%[^A-Za-z]' + @SearchTxt + '[^A-Za-z]%'
OR Col LIKE '%[^A-Za-z]' + @SearchTxt
```

For further reading, Here's Microsoft's documentation on [Pattern Matching in Search Conditions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I think this will work for my case, although I may have to work on the query speed now.

Answer (score 0):

```
    --Try this code it may meet your requirement
DECLARE @SearchTxt Varchar(20)='SearchWord'    
SELECT TOP 1 * from #TempTable
WHERE CHARINDEX(@SearchTxt,CONCAT(Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4))>0
```